# DTD Definition two children with the same childs

Tags: xml, dtd

I got three elements defined in a dtd which have the same child element names. What is the correct syntax for:

1. for all children having the same definition
2. elements having different children definitions

Example idea: is this valid?

```
<!ELEMENT one ( childone?, childtwo? ) >
<!ELEMENT two ( childone?, childtwo? ) >
<!ELEMENT three ( childone?, childtwo? ) >
    <!ELEMENT childone ( #PCDATA ) >
    <!ELEMENT childtwo ( #PCDATA ) >
```

I appreciate your help! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your example idea is valid for your first scenario (*for all children having the same definition*).

Your second scenario (*elements having different children definitions*) isn't possible. You're only allowed to have one declaration per element. You would have to declare new elements with unique names.

Comment: Problem is that I get problems validating a xml document having the first structure. You have any experiences with this?

Comment: @Manuel - What kind of validation problems do you have? Can you post an example?

Comment: Unluckily I cannot show a example since it includes confidential customer data. Tried to validate in adobe dreamweaver. To problems validating the dtd, however it says the childone and childtwo are not expected childs of two and three